# Can we animate a CSS change with a State?

Tags: css, reactjs, state

I have a Sidebar on left of my App, and it is set on 300px wide. When I click on a button, the Sidebar goes from 300px to 50px.

I change this width with a state :

```
const [isMinimized, setIsMinimized] = useState(false);

[...]

<div className={`${isMinimized ? 'w-16' : '2xl:w-80 w-56'} relative bg-white`}>
```

I'd like to set an animation when the sidebar minimize. I tried to add an animation on my div, but does not work.

Is it possible ?

Comment: I guess you are using tailwind. WHy don't you add a transition className to your `div` ? if you just want a transition when going from w-56 to w-16 ?

Comment: @MihaiT this is what I tried, but no animation after that

Comment: I posted an answer with a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `transition-width` so tailwind adds `transition-property:width` to the element's style properties.

You can do this all within JSX with tailwind classes. No need for other code.
Check below

```js
function MyApp() {
  const [isMinimized, setIsMinimized] = React.useState(false);

  return ( 
      <div >
        <div 
          className = {
          `${isMinimized ? 'w-16' : '2xl:w-80 w-56'} relative bg-black duration-1000 transition-width ease-in-out`
        } >
          MY DIV 
        </div> 
          <button 
            onClick = {() => setIsMinimized(!isMinimized)} 
          > 
          CLICK 
          </button> 
      </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render( <
  MyApp / >
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Or see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zk81oxev/)

If you want to add custom transition durations or behaviors you would need to change tailwind config. Read more here [tailwind transition](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property)

Comment: ```transition-width``` made it work. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a className when isMinimized is true ( for Example isMinimzed ? 'animatedScrollbar w-16' : '2xl:w-80 w-56') and add your transition as css using the className of the minimized state .

Comment: The animation is not taken in consideration :/

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `Web Animation API`

First create a `ref` object of the element you change its width.

```
const ref = useRef(null);
```

And use it:

```
<div ref={ref} className={relative bg-white`}>
```

Call this function on click.

```
  const onClick = () => {
    const { current } = ref;
    if (current) {
      const keyframe = [{ width: "300px" }, { width: "50px" }];
      const options = {
        duration: 1000,
        fill: "forwards",
        delay: 0,
        easing: "ease-in",
      };
      const newKeyframeEffect = new KeyframeEffect(current, keyframe, options);
      const animation = new Animation(newKeyframeEffect, document.timeline);
      animation.play();
      animation.onfinish = () => {
        
      }
    }
  };
```

Do whatever you need in `onfinish` functoin.

---

If you need to change the width of the element back to `300px`, do this:

Track if the element is expanded.

```
const [isExpended, setIsExpended] = useState(false)
```

If expanded, change its width from `300px` to `50px`. Else vise versa.

```
const keyframe = isExpended ? [{ width: "50px" }, { width: "300px" }]: [{ width: "300px" }, { width: "50px" }];
```

When the animation finishes, change the `isExpended` state.

```
 setIsExpended(!isExpended)
```

#### Example code

```
const App  = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null)

    const [isExpended, setIsExpended] = useState(false)

    const onClick = () => {
        const { current } = ref;
        if (current) {
            const keyframe = isExpended ? [{ width: "50px" }, { width: "300px" }]: [{ width: "300px" }, { width: "50px" }];

            const options = {
                duration: 1000,
                fill: "forwards",
                delay: 0,
                easing: "ease-in",
            };
            const newKeyframeEffect = new KeyframeEffect(current, keyframe, options);
            const animation = new Animation(newKeyframeEffect, document.timeline);
            animation.play();
            animation.onfinish = () =>  setIsExpended(!isExpended);
        }
    };

    return <div ref={ref} style={{width: "300px", background: "red"}}>
        <button onClick={onClick} type="button">Click</button>
    </div>
}
```

## Try this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-17rkkx?file=src%2FApp.js

#### Reference

1. useRef - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref
2. Web Animation API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API

Comment: why use a bunch of other stuff, add 100 lines of code, when you can do this with just some classNames ?